# how to convert latest 2 dates per category in a dataframe column to strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have this Pandas dataframe

```
   category       date       value
0      A6TCE 2023-01-06         NaN
1      A6TCE 2023-01-09         NaN
2       BDTI 2023-01-06         NaN
3       BDTI 2023-01-09         NaN
4      S2TCE 2023-01-06         NaN
5      S2TCE 2023-01-09         NaN
6        TD1 2023-01-06       38.67
7        TD1 2023-01-09       37.39
8       TD14 2023-01-09      250.31
9       TD14 2023-01-10      248.31
10      TD15 2023-01-06       54.03
11      TD15 2023-01-09       52.36
12      TD18 2023-01-06      425.08
13      TD18 2023-01-09      417.08
14      TD19 2023-01-06      182.94
15      TD19 2023-01-09      201.38
16       TD2 2023-01-06       53.42
17       TD2 2023-01-09       51.59
18      TD20 2023-01-06       92.05
19      TD20 2023-01-09       93.95
20      TD21 2023-01-06      314.00
21      TD21 2023-01-09      301.00
22      TD22 2023-01-06  8437500.00
23      TD22 2023-01-09  8411111.00
24      TD23 2023-01-06       68.19
25      TD23 2023-01-09       67.38
26      TD25 2023-01-06      161.43
27      TD25 2023-01-09      151.43
28      TD26 2023-01-06      140.00
29      TD26 2023-01-09      137.81
30      TD3C 2023-01-06       52.91
31      TD3C 2023-01-09       50.77
32       TD6 2023-01-06      169.61
33       TD6 2023-01-09      168.67
34       TD7 2023-01-06      168.56
35       TD7 2023-01-09      168.25
36       TD8 2023-01-09      242.86
37       TD8 2023-01-10      241.79
38       TD9 2023-01-06      129.38
39       TD9 2023-01-09      128.44
40     V2TCE 2023-01-06         NaN
41     V2TCE 2023-01-09         NaN
```

They are the data in a ts with the latest 2 available dates, different categories don't have the same dates, for example TD8's latest 2 dates are 10th and 9th Jan while others are 06th and 09th Jan and we couldn't know this before retrieving the data.

I wish to replace the latest date per each category by the string "2nd day" and earlier date with "1st day", so it looks like this (extract from the middle)

```
    34       TD7 1st day      168.56
    35       TD7 2nd day      168.25
    36       TD8 1st day      242.86
    37       TD8 2nd day      241.79
    38       TD9 1st day      129.38
    39       TD9 2nd day      128.44
```

What I tried:, as I thought they would always give the same dates, I did

```
df_last_2d["date"] = df_last_2d["date"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
days= dict(zip(sorted(df_last_2d["date"].unique()),["1st day","2nd day"]))
df_last_2d["date"] = df_last_2d["date"].apply(lambda x: days[x])
```

then the last line would fail

```
    df_last_2d["date"] = df_last_2d["date"].apply(lambda x: days[x])

KeyError: '2023-01-10'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
import inflect
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def convert_date(s):
    sum = pd.Series(np.ones(len(s)), index=s.index).astype(int)
    count = sum.cumsum()
    d = inflect.engine()
    s = count.apply(lambda x: d.ordinal(x) + ' day')
    return s

df['date']=df.groupby('category')['date'].transform(convert_date)
print(df)

  category     date       value
0     A6TCE  1st day         NaN
1     A6TCE  2nd day         NaN
2      BDTI  1st day         NaN
3      BDTI  2nd day         NaN
4     S2TCE  1st day         NaN
5     S2TCE  2nd day         NaN
6       TD1  1st day       38.67
7       TD1  2nd day       37.39
8      TD14  1st day      250.31
9      TD14  2nd day      248.31
10     TD15  1st day       54.03
11     TD15  2nd day       52.36
12     TD18  1st day      425.08
13     TD18  2nd day      417.08
14     TD19  1st day      182.94
15     TD19  2nd day      201.38
16      TD2  1st day       53.42
17      TD2  2nd day       51.59
18     TD20  1st day       92.05
19     TD20  2nd day       93.95
20     TD21  1st day      314.00
21     TD21  2nd day      301.00
22     TD22  1st day  8437500.00
23     TD22  2nd day  8411111.00
...
24     TD23  1st day       68.19
25     TD23  2nd day       67.38
26     TD25  1st day      161.43
27     TD25  2nd day      151.43
```

which will convert your first and second dates to a string. Because we are using `.transform()` the changed values can be easily put back into the dataframe as transform saves the indices.

You'll also need to `pip install inflect` for converting integers to ordinal numbers.